# Monitors don't show up in Display Arrangement preferences

Tags: display, macos

I have two external monitors on my MacBook Pro 2015 15" and I was doing an adjustment on the display arrangement yesterday when suddenly the displays on the arrangement tab gone.

[image]

I tried already:

1. Restart the computer
2. Unplug and plug all the cables
3. Change cables
4. Reset NVRAM
5. Reset SMC
6. Click on detect displays
7. Create another admin user

The strange thing is when I click on Mirror Displays, the displays appear but right after I unmark that they're gone again.

[image]

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running, on which hardware?

Comment: Last one, 10.12.4 - MacBook Pro 2015 15". 
http://imgur.com/a/g3giE
http://imgur.com/ynEhEIi

Comment: Is anything showing up on the displays?  Also, did you try unsetting the "adjustment," whatever that was?

Comment: @Allan yes, the displays works perfectly, but I can't move windows between them. The adjustment I was doing was simple moving the displays to a better arrangement.

Comment: I have the same problem, when i press gather windows, the settings window pops up for the screen im using.

Comment: I have the same issue with no solution. The windows _did_ originally appear, but after re-arranging a bit, they vanished and I cannot get them back. FWIW, I experience this behavior when I have my macbook pro 15" hooked up to a 27" Apple display and a 23" HP display. If I unplug the HP display, the icons show up and I can re-arrange. Similarly, if I unplug the Apple display and leave the HP only, the icons show up and I can re-arrange. I can only infer that this means that for some reason the two monitors are incompatible with each other?

Comment: I was able to somehow fix this by changing the rotation on one of the monitors. Not sure how/why that fixed it, but it did!

Comment: I have the same issue, can someone post this bug to iOS team?